# На linux mint постоянно отключается wi-fi.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, скрипт, linux-mint

У меня linux mint 18.1 Kernel: 4.7.0-040700-generic i686. У меня проблема, которая заключается в том, что **wi-fi сам по себе отлючается**. У меня стоит nm-applet, где я заново включаю wi-fi. Я менял mint на ubunta (ubuntu), nm-applet на wicd. Это не помогает. **На windows такой проблемы нет** и никогда не было, там wi-fi работает стабильно. Т.е. это не проблема самого адаптера как устройства.
Информация по адаптеру:
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller 
driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI

Я пришел к выводу, что самое простое **решение будет написать скрипт**, который каждую секунду будет проверять включен wi-fi или нет, и если выключен, то переподключать. **Но пока непродвинулся**, не могу найти команды, которые бы включали wi-fi или выключали. Нашел, что можно выключить интернет если вбить sudo killall wpa_supplicant но эта команда выключает что то большее, чем просто wi-fi.

*Так вот вопрос, может кто помочь с примером команд, которые могли бы помочь, или помочь в понимание причин возникновения такой ситуации*.

Comment: А если в нетворк менеджере поставить галку "подключаться к этой сети автоматом"?

Comment: в wicd я такой пункт находил и он не работал. И тут тоже он стоит и это не помогает. Тут проблема, что wi-fi просто берет и отключается. Т.е. это можно увидеть даже через терминал.
как только он вырубается написано
Tx-Power=off
если в NM-applet нажать включить wifi, то будет написано
Tx-Power=20 dBm

Т.е. я в этом состояние даже не вижу сети. потому что "как бы" нет обородования в компьютере, которое способновидеть. Ну или просто он с**а выключился.

Comment: Информацию, которую вы привели по карте, не про Wi-Fi, отключение передатчика скорее всего имеет отношение к фирмвари, драйверу и управлению питанием. Первая рекомендация - погуглить на предмет таких же ошибок, вторая - попробовать собрать ядро из апстрима или Linux-next.

Comment: искал не нашел решенных подобных проблем. Вот считаю лучший способ скрипт сделать. Что касается ядра, ставил но не линукс-некст. Как это ядро может мне помочь?

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы последовали моему совету и обновили вопрос, чтобы там была отражена актуальная информация. Делайте ваше домашнее задание перед тем, как задать вопрос, а не после. Удачи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как в дальнейшем оказалось, виноват был вовсе не линукс, а wifi адаптер в ноутбуке. Если стукнуть слегка пальцем, где он находиться, или даже прижать в том месте пальцем, wifi тут же вырубиться.

Comment: А почему в винде работало?

Comment: Вы знаете, решил заново проверить, раз располагаю новыми сведениями. Включил виндовс, начал снова стучать в том месте и он вырубился. Но !!!! вырубался с большим трудом, чем на линуксе. Не знаю, с чем это связано, но сила щелчков различается на порядок.